# a javascript fuction doesn't execute when i echo that in php code

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to echo the following html code on my page. But the `onclick` event doesn't work when I do this. the `$senduser` has the correct value

```
$table1="<div id='sendmsg' class='row'>
<div class='col-lg-6'>
<textarea id='msg' cols='40' placeholder='Write your message here...'></textarea>
</div><div class='col-lg-2' >
<button type='button' onClick='sendmsg(".$senduser.")' class='btn btn-success' value='send' id='msgbtn'>Send to</button></div></div>";

echo $table1;
```

my javascript function:

```
function sendmsg(senduser){
  alert(senduser);
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Alert doesn't show anything.

Comment: Corrected some syntax, added block ticks around what was needed, and removed unnecessary "please" and "thank" from the question :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$senduser` is probably a string and as you don't quote it, it is interpreted as a (undefined...) variable in javascript.

You need to quote it:

```
...
<button type='button' onClick='sendmsg(\"".$senduser."\")' class='btn btn-success' ...
 //                                    ^^ here        ^^ and here
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're wrapped the javaScript in a script tag

```
<script>
   function sendmsg(senduser){
          alert(senduser);
          .
          .
          .
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php 
$senduser = '1';
$table1="<div id='sendmsg' class='row'>
<div class='col-lg-6'>
<textarea id='msg' cols='40' placeholder='Write your message here...'></textarea>
</div><div class='col-lg-2' >
<button type='button' onClick='sendmsg(".$senduser.")' class='btn btn-success' value='send' id='msgbtn'>Send to</button></div></div>";

echo $table1; ?>

<script>
function sendmsg(senduser){
  alert(senduser); 
}
</script>
```