# Javascript "onclick" doesn't work embed with html & php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this delete link with a javascript who will promt Yes or No.
But i got nothing promted. I can guess it´s the escaping from php etc. who puts stop in my code? The "onclick" uses "'". and the message uses "'". Is that the problem? And how do i solve it?

**PHP/JS**

```
echo "<td><a href='time.php?id=".$row['id']."' onclick='return confirm('Are you sure to delete this ?');'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger'></span></a></td>";
```

Comment: Same sort of question posted 35 minutes ago  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877278/a-javascript-fuction-doesnt-execute-when-i-echo-that-in-php-code#answer-28877365

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not escape the quotes around "Are you sure...". Escape them using a `\`:

```
echo "<td><a href='time.php?id=".$row['id']."' onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure to delete this ?\");'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger'></span></a></td>";
```

This will output the following HTML:

```
<td><a href='time.php?id=XX' onclick='return confirm("Are you sure to delete this ?");'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger'></span></a></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have problem with quotes. Pass it properly will resolved the problem.

Do like this:

```
echo "<td><a href='time.php?id=".$row['id']."' onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure to delete this ?\");'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger'></span></a></td>";
```

Let me know for further query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this You forget to use `\` in your code

```
echo "<td><a href='time.php?id=".$row['id']."' onclick='return confirm(\"Are you sure to delete this ?\");'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove text-danger'></span></a></td>";
```